# C code counting occurrences in Matrix using sub matrices and MPI Parallelization

Tags: c, matrix, mpi, find-occurrences

I have an assignment to take in a 16 by 16 array of random numbers between 0-31 from a text file. I have been able to read in the matrix and allocate it to a 2D array called arr1. Now I need to use MPI to make my code work when parallelized over 1,4,8,16,32 cores per processor. Can someone show me how to weave in the MPI calls to split up the large matrix into varying sizes of submatrices depending on number of processors? Then use MPI to send, receive, etc. I want each node to count the occurrences of its sub matrix and the root node to combine them all and print out final tally.

```
//#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    int MAXR,MAXC;
    MAXR= 16; MAXC=16;
    int arr1[MAXR][MAXC],i,j;
    FILE *fp;
    fp =fopen("arrays16.txt","r");

    for(i=0;i<MAXR;i++) // this loop takes the information from .txt file and puts it into arr1 matrix
    {
        for(j=0;j<MAXC;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d\t",&arr1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<MAXR;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<MAXC;j++)

            printf("%d\t",arr1[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    //printf("%d\t",arr1[1][2]);


    int occurrences[3][33] = {{0}};

    occurrences[0][0] = 0;
    occurrences[0][1] = 1;
    occurrences[0][2] = 2;
    occurrences[0][3] = 3;
    occurrences[0][4] = 4;
    occurrences[0][5] = 5;
    occurrences[0][6] = 6;
    occurrences[0][7] = 7;
    occurrences[0][8] = 8;
    occurrences[0][9] = 9;
    occurrences[0][10] = 10;
    occurrences[0][11] = 11;
    occurrences[0][12] = 12;
    occurrences[0][13] = 13;
    occurrences[0][14] = 14;
    occurrences[0][15] = 15;
    occurrences[0][16] = 16;
    occurrences[0][17] = 17;
    occurrences[0][18] = 18;
    occurrences[0][19] = 19;
    occurrences[0][20] = 20;
    occurrences[0][21] = 21;
    occurrences[0][22] = 22;
    occurrences[0][23] = 23;
    occurrences[0][24] = 24;
    occurrences[0][25] = 25;
    occurrences[0][26] = 26;
    occurrences[0][27] = 27;
    occurrences[0][28] = 28;
    occurrences[0][29] = 29;
    occurrences[0][30] = 30;
    occurrences[0][31] = 31;




    // for(j=1;j<33;j++)
        //{
        //   printf("%d",occurrences[1][j]);
        //  }
    //printf("\n\n");

    int k;
    int count;

    for(k=0; k <= 31; k++)  {
        count = 0;
        for (i=0; i<= MAXR-1; i++) {

            for(j=0;j<=MAXC-1;j++) {

                if(arr1[i][j] == occurrences[0][k]) {
                    count++;
                    occurrences[1][k] = count;
                    printf("Occurrences of %d =  , are equal to = %d\n",arr1[i][j], occurrences[1][k]);
                    //break;
                }
                else {
                }

            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<32;j++)

            printf("%d\t",occurrences[i][j]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        for(j=0;j<=32;j++)

            printf("%d\t",occurrences[i][j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us your MPI part of the program, at least what have you tried. One strategy is to read the file on rank 0, distribute the parts of the matrix across all other ranks (each rank gets only a portion), apply you counting code (at this point for readability stored in a function), and collect the results from all ranks using preferably one of the collective MPI communication functions. You can try the above and ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Simple partitioning would be to have each process (rank) to obtain some number of rows in the matrix (e.g. since here you have 16 rows for 4 ranks that would be 4 rows per rank). In your case though you also have the 32 ranks requirement which would mean you would either split a flat 256 element array or for instance, give each rank half of a row.